# I have problem in Unity Registry Packages

Tags: unity-game-engine, package

Hello i am being confused about unity packages. My question is basically that can i use unity registry packages in my commercial game and if it is legal then will unity cut some money from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages developed by Unity (including the packages listed in the Package Manager by default) are included under the same terms as the Unity editor/engine. Using them makes no difference to your agreement with Unity regarding profits.